# TypeError: Cannot read property 'telephoneno' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying out a simple program on React JS and the code is as follows

```
class Employee extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            address: '',
            city: '',
            telephoneno: '',
            stdcode: ''
                        
        }

        // Other event handlers goes here
        this.handlePhoneNoChange = this.handlePhoneNoChange(this);
    }

    handlePhoneNoChange(event) { 
        this.setState({ telephoneno: event.target.telephoneno });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <center>
                <div>

                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm w-50">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Phone No</span>
                        </div>
                            
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No" id="phoneno" aria-label="PhoneNo" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" onChange={ this.handlePhoneNoChange } value={ this.state.telephoneno } /><br/>
                    </div><br/>
           
                 </div>  
            </center>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Employee;
```

It errors with `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'telephoneno'` of undefined'.

I am trying to understand the concept here.

Why it reports error only for 'telephoneno' and not other other fields ?  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked what you receive as `event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is this line:

```
this.handlePhoneNoChange = this.handlePhoneNoChange(this);
```

If you notice carefully, you are missing `.bind`. Due to this, you are calling it with `this` as event. Your component does not have `target` property in it and hence it throws the error.

Fix for the error is:

```
this.handlePhoneNoChange = this.handlePhoneNoChange.bind(this);
```

However it will not fix problems highlighted in other answers. Please refer them as well

---

As rightly mentioned by [Kalhan. Toress](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032751/kalhan-toress), you may also use an arrow function. I'm attaching reference to Docs where both approaches have been depicted

#### Reference:

- [React Docs - Handle Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: or use arraow functions

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the correct way to use state in react stateful component, use `props` as a parameter in the `constructor` and `super` function

```js
  constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            address: '',
            city: '',
            telephoneno: '',
            stdcode: ''
                        
        }
  }
```

and update this line:

```
this.setState({ telephoneno: event.target.value});
```

I recomnded to use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instad using statefull class.

Answer (score 0):

*event.target.value* basically retrieves value of whatever input it was called on.

In this case, the value of  *telephoneno* input can be accessed through event.target.value

So, the correct way of using the event is,

```
handlePhoneNoChange(event) { 
   this.setState({ telephoneno: event.target.value });
}
```

and you should bind it like this,

```
this.handlePhoneNoChange = this.handlePhoneNoChange.bind(this);
```

Better if you can use arrow functions in onChange event in your inputs,

```
onChange={ (e) => this.handlePhoneNoChange(e) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well.  Now, I understood the concept

Comment: Happy to hear that. Good luck with your work @SathishKumar